# How to find the ruler position from an image by using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I have to find the ruler position from an image by using opencv.I am able to detect the color of the ruler(green). How can i read all the pixel from an image and get the upper and lower position of ruler.

```
void findrulerPosition(cv::Mat image, int indx) {
std::stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
ss << indx;//add number to the stream

cv::Mat hsv;
cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

String filename = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "hsv" + ss.str() + ".png";
imwrite(filename, hsv );

cv::Mat hsvbw;
inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(30,0,0), cv::Scalar(80, 255, 255), hsvbw);
//inRange(hsv, cv::Scalar(12,255,255), cv::Scalar(23, 245, 255), hsvbw);
   //inRange(image, cv::Scalar(0,64,255), cv::Scalar(0, 207, 255), hsvbw);

filename = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "hsvbw" + ss.str() + ".png";
imwrite(filename, hsvbw );


vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(hsvbw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cv::Mat dst = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
drawContours(dst, contours, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);

this->cmpddst &=  dst;
dst &= image;
this->cmpddst &=  image;

filename = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "cmpddst" + ss.str() + ".png";
imwrite(filename, this->cmpddst );


filename = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "dst" + ss.str() + ".png";
imwrite(filename, dst );
```

}

Comment: i am new here so not allowed to upload image

Comment: @kashifhussain : upload image in imageshack.us or any other image sharing sites (google for it) and provide the link here.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK . thanks. links is http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/571/dst27.png/ how i will get the upper and lower position of the ruler? 2 rulere are in the image

Comment: @kashifhussain please, take a look at my answer and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Astor Thanks for help. I tried you code its working well . I have 2 question relating code. where you are matching the low and up position for ruler. when i run code the the result for low and up is Low( 6 ,478) and up(4 ,464) and how i will  do the same thing (low and up) for the second ruler because in output image the pink color it shows only for one ruler. once again thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

1. A bit improved your green range because yours is not detecting green color - it's detecting many other colors.
2. Find contours on image.
3. Find contour with area bigger than 100.
4. Find up and low points of contour.
5. Draw these 2 points.

```cpp
Mat src = imread("input.png"), tmp;
cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_BGR2HSV_FULL);
inRange(tmp, Scalar(50, 50, 50), Scalar(70, 255, 255), tmp);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(tmp, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

int upY = INT_MAX, lowY = 0, upX, lowX;
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (contourArea(contours[i]) > 100)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<contours[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (contours[i][j].y > lowY)
            {
                lowY = contours[i][j].y;
                lowX = contours[i][j].x;
            }
            if (contours[i][j].y < upY)
            {
                upY = contours[i][j].y;
                upX = contours[i][j].x;
            }
        }

        cout << "low = (" << lowX << ", " << lowY << ")"<<  endl
             << "up  = (" << upX << ", " << upY << ")"<<  endl;
        break;
    }
}

circle(src, Point(lowX, lowY), 3, Scalar(255, 0, 255));
circle(src, Point(upX, upY), 3, Scalar(255, 0, 255));

imshow("Window", src);
waitKey();
```

Here's result:

[image]